# Apply VBA Code To More Rows or Range of Rows

Tags: excel, vba, redirect, apply, rows

I am just trying to apply that is working in row only.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("P6:R6")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cells(O6, O15).Select

End Sub
```

Goal: Click specific cells to be redirected to a cell( I will protect those cells except for the target cell.) I want it to work to specific range of rows only but not continuous. There will be gaps between rows I want this code to apply.

Steps I Found So Far: The formula above I found online and that only works in 1 row.

Comment: What specific ranges do you want it to be applied to, and how are the "destination" ranges related to the clicked-on ranges?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'single-cell selections only
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P6:R100")) Is Nothing Then
        'Do not need to disable events before selecting, since we're not
        '   selecting a range in the monitored region 
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, "O").Resize(10).Select
    End If

End Sub
```